# To lookup multiple conditions in different sheet and show all result in column by column- possible to do it with excel formula or vba is required?

Tags: excel, vba

need some help on my excel production report.

I want to Lookup for the **daily unique ID**, **gram** and **pieces** from **Sheet 1** into **Sheet 2**.

The daily unique ID consists of up to **5 categories**.

Each day, there could be up to a **maximum of 3 unique ID produced** with each one having different categories (some have 2 same categories with different grams and pieces. It need to be shown in a separate column in Sheet 2), grams and pieces.

I came out with an excel formula but it only works IF there is only one daily unique ID per day. If there is more than one unique ID, this formula fails as it only captures the first one.

Please see my formula below

I2:I100 is the gram in Sheet 1

E2:E100 is the "unique code-category" in Sheet 1

D11 is the unique code in Sheet 2

P11 is the type of categories

`{=IFERROR(INDEX('A'!$I$2:$I$100,SMALL(IF(($D$11&"-"&$P$11)='A'!$E$2:$E$100,MATCH(ROW('A'!$E$2:$E$100),ROW('A'!$E$2:$E$100)),""),ROWS($A$1:$A1))),"")}`

Is there a way I could capture everything?

Can I do it with excel formula or a VBA is required?

I have tried many different formulas but nothing came out right, please help :(

Please let me know if my explanation isn't clear. Thanks.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpDbc.png)
[Sheet 2 (Final Report)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hrLi.png)

Comment: Can you upload a Screen Capture?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for replying. I have uploaded 2 screen capture of my excel. thanks

Comment: Did you try `SUMIFS`? Just make a search for the items by `VLOOKUP` and the quantities by `SUMIFS`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try. But I think SUMIFS don't do much because I need to separate each line even when they are same ID and same categories?